# Ghostscript BMP Scaling

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, bmp, postscript

I am attempting to use Ghostscript to convert a PS file first to PDF, then to BMP, along with some scaling at both conversions.

To convert my PS file to PDF, here are my arguments:

```
 -g2838x4551 -r720 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=""FILE PATH TO DUMP PDF IN HERE"" -c save pop -f ""FILE PATH TO GRAB PS FROM HERE""
```

this part of my code is working fine.

To convert my new PDF file to BMP, here are my arguments:

```
 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bmp256 -sOutputFile=""OUTPUT BMP FILE LOCATION"" " & PDF FILE LOCATION & "
```

In terms of just converting from PDF to BMP, this is working.  However, I'd like to scale it up a bit, to 374x635 pixels.  I have attempted to do this with various switches, such as

-g374X635

-dPDFFITPage

-dDEVICEWIDTH=374 -dDEVICEHEIGHT=635

-dFIXEDMEDIA

or some combination of the above.  The -dDEVICEWIDTH and -dDEVICEHEIGHT switches don't seem to be working at all, and while -g374x635 is increasing the BMP to the correct size, it seems like it's just adding white space to get to the correct size, instead of scaling the entire PDF up the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you explained why you want to produce a PDF from the PostScript and BMP from the PDF, instead of producing both from the same input....

`DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS` and `DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS` need to be used in combination with `FIXEDMEDIA` if you want to then use `FitPage`, as all they do is set the **current** media size which can then be overridden, unless you fix it.

The PDF interpreter calls `setpagedevice` for every page, because PDF files can contain different media sizes for each page, so unless you set `FIXEDMEDIA` it will resize each page of output for you.

`-g` silently sets `FIXEDMEDIA`.

The page fitting doesn't do scaling up, only down, for larger media than requested it honours the original media size and centres it on the new (larger) media.

Given that you have already created a PDF file where every page is the same fixed size, the easiest way to alter the output dimensions (in pixels) then, is simply to alter the resolution.

Now PDF files don't have a resolution as such, because they aren't a strictly bitmap format, so by setting a fixed (in pixels) size and a resolution in the original conversion to PDF what you are actually doing is creating a fixed **media** size. In this case you are creating a PDF file where the media size is 2838/720 by 4551/720 = 3.941666 inches by 6.3208333 inches.

When you render to a bitmap, the size of the bitmap (in pixels) is given by the media size in inches * the resolution in dpi. So working backwards, knowing that the desired size is 374x635 and the media size above, the required resolution is:

```
374 / 3.9416666 = 94.8837
635 / 6.3208333 = 100.4614
```

So using `-r95x100` would produce more or less the output size you want. Note that in your original PDF creation step, you do not need `-c save pop -f`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I don't actually need the PDF, but I had trouble setting up the command to go from PS straight to BMP, so I used the PDF as an intermediate step.  If I could do it without the PDF, that'd be great as I was planning on deleting it after it was done converting to BMP.  

I will test the -r95x100 on my PDF -> BMP command to see if this works.

Comment: You can use the same command with PostScript input as PDF input. You can easily set the desired bitmap size using -g and FitPage. Of course the calculation I showed above may well no longer be correct, because you didn't say what the requested media in the PostScript program is. I was able to use the known fixed media size from the PDF creation for the calculation, you will need to find the requested media size and then set the -g and -r values appropriately.